# Shimano Hydraulic disc brakes- Lever compatibility

Tags: shimano, disc-brake, hydraulic-disc-brake, brake-levers

I am looking for practical advice on compatibility between various Shimano hydraulic disc brakes, especially the lever assembly. Currently I have two separate sets, one M446 Left lever, attached to a short hose and a caliper (front brake) and one M395 Right lever with a long hose (rear brake). I would like to have the right hand brake to be the front brake. Can I simply disconnect the brake hose and swap the levers? Do I need new 'Olives'(line inserts)?

I know some Shimano disc brakes use a Banjo bolt connection, but this is not the case for my brakes. Some sites claim that all Shimano hydraulic parts are interchangeable. Others claim that there are very small differences in the brake hose diameter for newer brakes. Is there anyone who has made such a setup work?

Answer (score 3):

According to these pages:

http://productinfo.shimano.com/#/spec/2.4/MTB/Brake%20%28Disc%20Brake%29?q=M446
http://productinfo.shimano.com/#/spec/2.4/MTB/Brake%20%28Disc%20Brake%29?q=M395

These brakes both use the same hose kit, SM-BH59-JK-SS.

In document EV-BR-M446-F, the connecting bolt unit has part number Y8H298010.
In document EV-BR-M395-F, the connecting bolt unit has part number Y8H598010.
For both, the Olive & Connecter Insert (barb) has part number Y8H298020.

I can find no information on the difference between Y8H298010 and Y8H598010, which may be superficial. **If you have the fluid and funnel necessary to bleed the brakes, I suggest you unscrew the two hoses and measure the threaded fitting.**